# Cast .Net object to another .Net object in IronPython, Dynamo

Tags: python, ironpython, autodesk, revit-api, revit

- the revit API IndependentTag.Create() method requires a Reference object as one of its inputs
- A Reference object is instantiated with a revit Element object
- I have bunch of revit Wall objects which inherit from the Element class
- in C# I can simply say:`Reference ref = new Reference(wall as Element);`
- clr.Convert does not cast correctly, just returns the object as a Wall again
- `ref = Reference(wall)` in python gives an exception that the reference cannot be used

Can one cast a .Net object to its parent object in python (iron python)?
I am trying to bandage up someone's dynamo/python script and that one object is mucking it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, if `wall` is of class `Wall` and that inherits from `Element`, there is no need to cast `wall` to `Element`. You can just use `wall` as is. It is already a `Wall` and therefore also an `Element`. I would assume the same applies in Python. I suggest you post a code snippet for better understanding.

Comment: I see what happened now, the error I was getting referred to a "Reference object" in a general sense... not the Autodesk.Revit.DB.Reference object I assumed it was, the debugging environment for python within dynamo is not the best.  I was creating the point input for IndependentTag.Create poorly.  You are correct, you can feed Reference a Wall object just fine!